# Error while executing npx react-native run-android ==> Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: react-native

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> Native libs debug enabled: false
> Android gradle plugin: 7.2.1
> Gradle: 7.5.1
> building Reanimated2
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadHermes UP-TO-DATE
> Download https:github.com/facebook/hermes/tarball/hermes-2022-09-14-RNv0.70.1-2a6b111ab289b55d7b78b5fdf105f466ba270fd7

> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost UP-TO-DATE
> Download https:boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.gz

> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadDoubleConversion UP-TO-DATE
> Download https:github.com/google/double-conversion/archive/v1.1.6.tar.gz

> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadFolly UP-TO-DATE
> Download https:github.com/facebook/folly/archive/v2021.07.22.00.tar.gz

> Task :react-native-reanimated:downloadGlog UP-TO-DATE
> Download https:github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.3.5.tar.gz

> Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https:docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
163 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 157 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HD:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=23 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fstack-protector-all -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\2w3pu2p1\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\2w3pu2p1\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -BD:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android.cxx\Debug\2w3pu2p1\arm64-v8a -GNinja -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DNATIVE_DEBUG=false -DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=70 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DBOOST_VERSION=1_76_0 -DNODE_MODULES_DIR=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules -DJS_RUNTIME=hermes -DJS_RUNTIME_DIR=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native\sdks\hermes -DCLIENT_SIDE_BUILD=true -DIS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED=false -DPLAYGROUND_APP_NAME=D:\c2c_mobile\android\app -DRNVERSION=70}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https:reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HD:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=23 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fstack-protector-all -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\2w3pu2p1\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\2w3pu2p1\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -BD:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android.cxx\Debug\2w3pu2p1\arm64-v8a -GNinja -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DNATIVE_DEBUG=false -DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=70 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DBOOST_VERSION=1_76_0 -DNODE_MODULES_DIR=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules -DJS_RUNTIME=hermes -DJS_RUNTIME_DIR=D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native\sdks\hermes -DCLIENT_SIDE_BUILD=true -DIS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED=false -DPLAYGROUND_APP_NAME=D:\c2c_mobile\android\app -DRNVERSION=70}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s

```
at makeError (D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\c2c_mobile\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 7):

The error is of reanimated library
if you Downgrad your reanimated library to 2.9.1 the app will start crashing
so
use react-native-reanimated 2.17.0 for react-native version > 0.70

npm i react-native-reanimated@2.17.0

Answer (score 6):

for those who uses m1 or m2 chip mac, the solution is installing rosetta.

softwareupdate --install-rosetta

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the above issue. please try reinstall reanimated version.

***1.npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
2.npm install react-native-reanimated@2.9.1***

it's *100% working for* me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Windows 11, react-native: "0.72.5", react-native-reanimated: "^3.5.4")

1. Run `cd android` in project directory
2. Open command prompt and run `gradlew clean`
3. Run `cd ..`, then run `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: To add to this answer, what worked in my case was running `gradlew installDebug` from the android folder instead of running `npx react-native run-android` from the root.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Windows 10, react-native 0.72.5, react-native-reanimated 3.5.4)

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what worked for me was to delete the **NDK** folder, for you, I can see that it's located here `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\`. Delete it, then do `./gradlew clean` and run `react-native run-android`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember for Windows go to the android folder of the project and run gradlew Clean (Without ./). Then back to folder root run npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

For those who are on windows, make sure that you have JAVA SDK installed and JAVA_HOME variable is added in Environment Variables....

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred me right after my computer power offed(Bad electricity). What I've done was to solve this issue that I deleted my node_modules in my Project and executed the install command.

```
npm install
```

And then after run my project with

```
npm run android
```

Command, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using m1 or m2 chip mac, the solution is to install Rosetta. Open a terminal and run

```bash
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

After doing that, do these steps:

1. `npm uninstall react-native-reanimated`
2. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`
3. `npm react-native-reanimated`
4. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`
5. run project

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues (I was using node v18, react native 0.73 and windows 11).

1/ remove node_modules (`rm -rf node_modules` if you are using git bash) 
2/ change to node v20 (`nvm list` -> `nvm use 20.X.X` (with me is 20.3.1)) 
3/ re-install node_modules (`npm i` or `yarn`)
4/ `cd android` -> `./gradlew clean` 
5/ `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`

Answer (score -1):

I can *find out the solution*.
you can below line in your babel.config.js file

plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],

and **Please refer this site** https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).