# Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] [CXX1428] exception while building Json

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to use the Drawer Navigator from React Navigation in my React Native project. I've come across a similar issue that many others have faced when attempting to run the React Native app after integrating react-native-reanimated into their project. unfortunately I am not able to find the solution for the exact issue that I have.

Here are my dependencies versions:

```
React Native version: 0.72.3
React Native Reanimated version: ^3.4.2
```

I've included a screenshot of my package.json file for reference.

[image: package json image]

When I initiate the app using the command react-native run-android, I encounter the following error:

```
[CXX1416] Could not find Ninja on PATH or in SDK CMake bin folders.
[CXX1416] Could not find Ninja on PATH or in SDK CMake bin folders.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> [CXX1416] Could not find Ninja on PATH or in SDK CMake bin folders.
```

I've also attached a screenshot of the error.
[image: encountered error in terminal]

Note: I am using Macbook Air M1 chip ventura 13.0 (22A380)

**EDIT:**

I assume Ninja is not installed or not properly configured in system's PATH. [Ninja-build link](https://ninja-build.org/)

So I just Installed Ninja with

```
brew install ninja
```

And ran the clean up
cd android
./gradlew clean

And restarted my project Now I am getting a different error

[image: Attached error screenshot]
Similar issue that has told in this stack overflow question:
[Error while executing npx react-native run-android ==> Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881553/error-while-executing-npx-react-native-run-android-execution-failed-for-task)

Comment: It might help to use ```useLegacyImplementation``` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817139/react-native-ios-drawer-partially-opened-on-login?noredirect=1#comment135424003_76817139)

Comment: @MichaelBahl unfortunately the above errors persists. adding       `useLegacyImplementation={true}` flag didn't works

Comment: What is your current ```com.android.tools.build:gradle```version?

Comment: @MichaelBahl My gradle version is 8.0.1, also I made a edit the question with the  approach I have tried earlier today. please take a look at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I am posting the answer it may help somebody.

I encountered an issue that seemed to be related to conflicting versions of react-native and react-native-reanimated packages. By following these steps, I was able to resolve the problem After exploring the issues, I found that downgrading both **react-native** and **react-native-reanimated** helped resolve the problem.
I am attaching the image of my updated dependencies without any issues:

[image: image of packagejson dependencies]

Also Its good to perform cleanup tasks after installing or uninstalling packages. This can help prevent a variety of unwanted issues.

```
cd android
```

To perform a Gradle clean:

```
./gradlew clean
```

To Clear the Gradle build cache:

```
./gradle cleanBuildCache
```

To clean the npm cache:

```
npm start --reset-cache
npm run android --reset-cache
npm run iOS --reset-cache
```

I also referred react-native drawer boilerplace code that someone did helped me to downgrade my project.
[Link to the github repo of react-native drawer boilerplate](https://github.com/iamitkhatkar/react-native-custom-drawer-boilerplate/)